# Channel creation failed. Hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**This is on a ubuntu 18.04 VPS**

**$ docker version**

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           20.10.8
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.16.6
Git commit:        3967b7d
Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:54:08 2021
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          20.10.8
API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.16.6
Git commit:       75249d8
Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:16 2021
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          1.4.9
GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
runc:
Version:          1.0.1
GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
docker-init:
Version:          0.19.0
GitCommit:        de40ad0

**$docker-compose version**

docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
docker-py version: 3.6.0
CPython version: 3.6.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

LOCAL_VERSION=2.2.4
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.2.4

I ran:
$./network.sh up (This is succesfull)
$./network.sh createChannel

But send me this.

neek_test@localhost:~/go/src/github.com/neek_test/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh createChannel
Creating channel 'mychannel'.
If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb
Generating channel genesis block 'mychannel.block'
/home/neek_test/go/src/github.com/neek_test/fabric-samples/test-network/../bin/configtxgen

- configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -channelID mychannel
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.039 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.059 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.059 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.059 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /home/neek_test/go/src/github.com/neek_test/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.062 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 005 Generating genesis block
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.062 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> WARN 006 Genesis block does not contain a consortiums group definition.  This block cannot be used for orderer bootstrap.
  2021-09-22 18:10:24.062 CDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
- res=0
  Creating channel mychannel
  Using organization 1

Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": read tcp 127.0.0.1:42722->127.0.0.1:7053: read: connection reset by peer

Channel creation failed.

What could I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been attempting to recreate your error but haven't been able to. It seems that configtxgen is successfully creating a genesis block for your channel, however osnadmin cannot join the first orderer to the channel.

Can you provide more context to your question? What version of Fabric are you using? Have you messed with any of the configuration yaml files in the test network?

If you are simply trying to run the test network tutorial, you can always wipe your local repositories and fetch the newest versions of the fabric and fabric-samples repositories then try again. Also, [this link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/docs/source/create_channel/create_channel_participation.md) might be of use for helping you understanding the updated, "system channel-less" way of how the configtxgen and osnadmin binaries work together to create an application channel.